# How can I find out if I am inside a specific IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

Let's say I'm a js script living inside a html page.  I need to know if I am inside a specific IFrame.

Something like

```
if (top.location.href === 'http://specificurl/') ...
```

However I need this working from any domain.

I have also tried adding a value to the window element in the iframe owner and checking on the child with the same result (permission error).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Guido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how I can do it in MY scenario.  Fortunately my client script (living in frame) gets loaded dynamically by one of my scripts.  I simply added a #anchor to the url and that was accessible inside the frame.

Very straight forward really.

Thanks for the help Graza, that product looks very interesting fortunately I don't need it.

Thanks

Guido

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done unless you have control over both pages/sites/domains (that is, the frame's page AND the main page).

If you do have control, check out the [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net) framework or google for "cross domain communication iframe"

And the reason this can't be done is simple security. Imagine if you visited a site that contained a frame which appeared to take up the whole page, and then visited your online banking site -> easy to see how malicious javascript could get all sorts of details, which is why it can only be done if the two sites/pages/domains are explicitly coded to work together

Comment: No I dont have control of both domains, I do however have control of the scripts in both pages.

Comment: Control over the scripts is as good as the domains. Check out the above framework or google search. It takes a bit of getting your head around, but easyXDM seems to do the trick, with cross-browser-compatibility as well.